# How to insert dates from a csv file which are in multiple formats into a column(whose data type is date i.e 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) of hive table

Tags: date, hive, insert, hiveql

I'm trying to insert data from a csv file into a hive table where date in csv files are in formats like 'mm/dd/yyyy','mm-dd-yyyy' which i have to insert in a hive table in a column whose data-type is date i.e 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Firstly i tried to load data from csv file inside a table whose date is stored with data-type as string. Then, i tried to insert the same data into a new table whose data-type is date but i was only able to load dates inside table of one format while other format stored as NULL.

```
create table sample1(order_id int, order_dt string);
load data local inpath "\home\cloudera\data.txt" into table sample1;

create table sample2(order_id int, order_dt date);   
insert into table sample2 select order_id, 
to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(order_dt,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-mm-dd')) 
from sample1;
```

csv file:

order_id   order_date

1       10/27/2016

2       10/27/2018

3       11/23/2016

4       09-23-2013

5       08-20-2010

6       05-13-2017

7       02/15/2009

output after:

select * from sample2;

1       2016-10-27

2       2018-10-27

3       2016-11-23

4       NULL

5       NULL

6       NULL

7       2009-02-15

Here, I'm getting NULL for other date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` function here. if first `to_date` function returns null then it will execute the 2nd argument, you can pass any number of patterns this way.

```
insert into table sample2 
select 
    order_id, 
    COALESCE(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(order_dt,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy-mm-dd')),to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(order_dt,'mm-dd-yyyy'),'yyyy-mm-dd'))) 
from sample1;
```